# How to call this.close in buildResult method when using Search Delegate (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a very simple SearchApp that has an AppBar with a search Icon and a text widget. When the search Icon is tapped, showSearch is called and the CustomSearchDelegate is called. How do I make it so that in the buildResults method, this.close is immediately called without returning a widget and the query is passed to the SearchApp stateless widget to be displayed on the Text widget.

Here is the code:

```
class SearchApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Search',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            //Don't block the main thread
            onPressed: () {
              showSearch(context: context, delegate: CustomSearchDelegate());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Text(query), // The query data should be displayed here
    );
  }
}

class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return <Widget>[Icon(Icons.close)];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // GO back to SearchApp page immediately with the query result
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Column();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realized I could edit the source code of the search class, so I copied and pasted the source code and under the Textfield, I simply deleted the showResult method and replaced it with close, so no results page would be shown. As for passing the query to the original page, all I had to do was store the value in an asynchronous variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use close() function without buildResults() you can override showResults()

```
  @override
  void showResults(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement showResults
    super.showResults(context);
  }
```

to this:

```
  @override
  void showResults(BuildContext context) {
    close(context, query);
  }
```

like this:

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return <Widget>[Icon(Icons.close)];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // unused
    return const SizedBox();
  }

  @override
  void showResults(BuildContext context) {
    close(context, query);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Column();
  }
}
```

call like this to get query result:

```
onPressed: () async {
  String? result = await showSearch(context: context, delegate: CustomSearchDelegate());
}
```